# use many input tag to search from database , JSP

Tags: sql, jsp, jdb

[image]

I have many case to search database, so i don't want repeat if/else statement, 
is there an other good solution ? 
nom and dd and ddd are input name,

Sorry for my bad english!

Answer (score 0):

```
String requete = "Select * from employees where 1=1 ";
if (!nom.isEmpty()) {
    requete += " and last_name like '"+nom+"%'";
}
if (!dd.isEmpty() && !ddd.isEmpty()) {
    requete  += " and hire_date between '"+dd+"' and '"+ddd+"';
}
```

This way you can optimiz, so you can get rid of the same if condition in the else block.